# Swagger With Karaf Integration

Tags: swagger, karaf

I am trying to integrate Karaf with Swagger for Rest-API Documentation following the link :http://cxf.apache.org/docs/swagger2feature.html
 I am ussing cxf 3.1.3. I am unable to find the `swagger as a karaf feature.` 
 i tried to resolve the swagger dependencies but unable to succeed.
Any Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a swagger 2.11 feature already configured at the servicemix repository, you can install it with the following steps:

```
feature:repo-add mvn:org.apache.servicemix.features/servicemix-features/7.0.1/xml/features
feature:install swagger-2.11
```